# How to draw circled transistors

Tags: circuitikz

How to draw [a circled transistor](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/BJT_NPN_symbol.svg) in `circuitikz`?

[image]

I did not find any info about circled transistors in [`circuitikzmanual.pdf`](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 11):

Since `circuitikz` is built upon `TikZ`, you can use `\draw` to draw a circle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[npn] (npn) {}
(npn.base) node[anchor=east] {B}
(npn.collector) node[anchor=south] {C}
(npn.emitter) node[anchor=north] {E};
\draw ($(npn)-(0.18,0)$) circle [radius=18pt];
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As it is noted in the comments, in the original solution the circle was wrong centered; **Kroll** suggested using the barycentre of the triangle with vertices in the base, the collector and the emitter, but this also produces the wrong result, as can be seen in the example below (which uses barycentric coordinates to easily obtain the coordinates for the center; the calculations are done automatically using a `\CalcC` command whose argument is the name used for the transistor):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\def\CalcC#1{%
\coordinate (base) at (#1.base);
\coordinate (collector) at (#1.collector);
\coordinate (emitter) at (#1.emitter);
\draw (barycentric cs:base=0.5,collector=0.5,emitter=0.5) circle [radius=14pt];
}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[npn] (name) {}
(name.base) node[anchor=east] {B}
(name.collector) node[anchor=south] {C}
(name.emitter) node[anchor=north] {E};
\CalcC{name}
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A little horizontal shift (obtained with a variation of the barycentric coordinate associated to the base anchor), produces a much better result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\def\CalcC#1{%
\coordinate (base) at (#1.B);
\coordinate (collector) at (#1.C);
\coordinate (emitter) at (#1.E);
\draw (barycentric cs:base=0.32,collector=0.5,emitter=0.5) circle [radius=14pt];
}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (0,0) node[npn] (name) {}
(name.base) node[anchor=east] {B}
(name.collector) node[anchor=south] {C}
(name.emitter) node[anchor=north] {E};
\CalcC{name}
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is wrong centered. The center of the circle must be in the center of the transistor.

Comment: i.e. in the center of the collector-emitter triangle or the center of the base-collector-emitter trapezoid. I think it's too complicated to define it manually. This feature should be implemented inside circuitikz.

Comment: @Kroll:please see my updated answer; now the center is automatically calculated using barycentric coordinates and you can easily change the horizontal component in the definition of `\CalcC` to place the center automatically in the desired position. Of course, the ultimate solution would be to ask the author of `circuitikz` to define this kind of transistor.